# either eof or bof is true but recordcount is greater than zero

Tags: c#, ado, recordset

I'm using a recordset in C# because my DLL is going to be used by a VBA application.
I'm getting the data from database using ADO.NET and filling the recordset manually.
This part is working fine, I use MoveFirst() and I can navigate through records.

But I need to Sort the data and after I set the Sort property of the recordset I can't use it anymore. It says BOF or EOF are both true but recordcount is near 300.000 so my recordset have data!
Why does this happen just after I set the Sort property?

I can't sort on database because I use a procedure of a database that isn't mine, I don't have access to it.

Code Example:

Proc call and recordset creation:

```
ADODB.Recordset ExecuteProcedure(string procedure, List<SqlParameter> parameters, List<Alias> alias)
    {
        SqlCommand commando = new SqlCommand(procedure, this.Connection);
        commando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        commando.CommandTimeout = this.TimeOut;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
            { commando.Parameters.Add(param); }
        };

        SqlDataReader dr = commando.ExecuteReader();

        ADODB.Recordset result = new ADODB.Recordset();
        result.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient;

        //create columns
        foreach (var item in alias.OrderBy(o => o.ColumnIndex).ToList())
        {
            Type fieldType = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (dr.GetName(i).Equals(item.ColumnName))
                {
                    fieldType = dr.GetFieldType(i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            result.Fields.Append(item.Alias
                , TranslateType(fieldType)
                , fieldType == typeof(String) ? 16384 : (fieldType == typeof(DateTime) ? 0 : int.MaxValue)
                , ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldIsNullable
                , null);
        }

        result.Open(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value
                , ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, 0);

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            result.AddNew(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            foreach (var item in alias.OrderBy(o => o.ColumnIndex).ToList())
            {
                result.Fields[item.ColumnIndex - 1].Value = dr[item.ColumnName];
            }
        }

        dr.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

Call to the methods:

```
var rs = myAccessManager.ExecuteProcedure("procedure", param, StringToDatatableAlias(colunas));

if (!rs.BOF)
    rs.MoveFirst();
//until this point, I can see de data on Immediate window. Everything is working fine
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
    rs.Sort = orderBy;
//after this point, I get the BOF or EOF are both true error when I try to access de data on recordset. But recordcount property is still above 300.000
```

Comment: There is no VBA in your question. By tagging it wrong you made a vba expert waste their time on a c# question.

Comment: What's the value of orderBy ?

Comment: @bgalea sorry, you are right

Comment: @Alex K. The value of orderBy is "Código_Cliente, Código_Operação, Data_de_Vcto". Those are 3 of the columns I create on my recordset

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the problem and a solution. I'm writting here why that was happening and how to solve if anyone get stuck with this in the future.

First of all the problem has ocurred by the way I've created recordset fields.
Especifically this line:

```
result.Fields.Append(item.Alias
            , TranslateType(fieldType)
            , fieldType == typeof(String) ? 16384 : (fieldType == typeof(DateTime) ? 0 : int.MaxValue)
            , ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldIsNullable
            , null);
```

I've defined the fields length using this clause `fieldType == typeof(String) ? 16384 : (fieldType == typeof(DateTime) ? 0 : int.MaxValue)` and the fields were too big. So big that recordset was unable to sort and give an exception. It's just got EOF and BOF = true and recordset became unacessible.

So what I've done to resolve this? I've used metadata info from the database fields to define the length for the recordset fields.

And this is how the code ends:

```
ADODB.Recordset ExecuteProcedure(string procedure, List<SqlParameter> parameters, List<Alias> alias)
{
    SqlCommand commando = new SqlCommand(procedure, this.Connection);
    commando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    commando.CommandTimeout = this.TimeOut;
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
        { commando.Parameters.Add(param); }
    };

    SqlDataReader dr = commando.ExecuteReader();

    ADODB.Recordset result = new ADODB.Recordset();
    result.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient;

    //get table schema
    DataTable schema = dr.GetSchemaTable();
    foreach (var item in alias.OrderBy(o => o.ColumnIndex).ToList())
    {
        Type fieldType = dr.GetFieldType(dr.GetOrdinal(item.ColumnName));

        result.Fields.Append(item.Alias
            , TranslateType(fieldType)
            , Convert.ToInt32(schema.Rows[dr.GetOrdinal(item.ColumnName)]["ColumnSize"])
            , schema.Rows[dr.GetOrdinal(item.ColumnName)]["AllowDBNull"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true") ? ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldIsNullable : ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldUnspecified
            , null);
    }

    result.Open(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            , ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, 0);


    while (dr.Read())
    {
        result.AddNew(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        foreach (var item in alias.OrderBy(o => o.ColumnIndex).ToList())
        {
            result.Fields[item.ColumnIndex - 1].Value = dr[item.ColumnName];
        }
    }

    dr.Close();

    return result;
}
```